# 'Missing subcircuit' when creating a Pspice library part from the OPA188 Spice file provided by TI

Tags: spice

I created a Pspice part using the Spice file provided by TI. When simulating, I get the following error:

ERROR(ORPSIM-15108): Subcircuit RNOISE_FREE_0 used by X_U1.XR101 is undefined
ERROR(ORPSIM-15108): Subcircuit RNOISE_FREE_0 used by X_U1.XR105 is undefined
ERROR(ORPSIM-15108): Subcircuit RNOISE_FREE_2 used by X_U1.XR104 is undefined
ERROR(ORPSIM-15108): Subcircuit RNOISE_FREE_0 used by X_U1.XR103 is undefined

Some of the lines with the offending subcircuits are as follows:

XR109_3 23 9 RNOISE_FREE_0
XR109_4 41 9 RNOISE_FREE_0

Would 'RNOISE_FREE...' be circuits recognized by TINA (TI's software) but not by PSPICE? 
Could I replace them with an equivalent?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you added the new .lib file in the Simulation Settings dialog?

Comment: It might also help to tell us which version of PSPICE you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have faced similar problem while executing one of my simulation circuits using `opa4132.lib` file. I have copied all files related to OPA4132 to PSpice library but it did not help. So then in  simulation settings, I have changed some limits value like (ABSTOL) and (ITL1) but still the same result.

Finally, I have done something which really helped me to solve this issue. You can try these steps:

1. In EDIT SIMULATION PROFILE window select "Configuration Files" menu
2. On left side when you select "Library" option, you can see one file named `nom.lib`. Here you need to add your `.lib` file. In my case it was OPA4132.
3. To do that go to browse option, in that select required `.lib` file and then click on "Add to Design" menu. Then click on OK.
4. Now you execute your simulation.

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have copied only the *OPA188 subcircuit* (.SUBCKT OPA188 ... till the nearest .ENDS statement) out of the *OPA188.lib* file provided by Texas Instruments. Am I right? Or what have you exactly done with the OPA188.lib file while making your own library item concerning this part?

**Copying only the OPA188 subcircuit, however, is not enough!**

There are a few other (nested) subcircuits defined in this library file, among them .SUBCKT RNOISE_FREE_0, .SUBCKT RNOISE_FREE_2, etc., that are used (called) within the main .SUBCKT OPA188 during simulation. You have to use the whole "*code*" part of the *OPA188.lib* file (copy it into "your" library).

The error message usually contains only a few first errors occurred after start of simulation, that's why the report doesn't contain all missing subcircuits (I'm sure there are more missing than those two there).