# Using PSPICE model of gate-driver from manufacturer

Tags: gate-driving, pspice, modeling, cadence

I have found a PSPICE model for a part I'm interested in.

ISL55110 Datasheet:
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/698/isl55110-11-1302115.pdf

Manufacturer PSPICE Model:
https://www.renesas.com/cn/zh/www/software/simulation/isl55110_spice_model.txt?key=7c34d7bf3964f39e34346fc510d75e83

---

In the past, when I needed to use manufacturer models of components in PSPICE, I would simply find a part that was already defined and had the same number of pins/parameters and copy-paste the code into the spice model editor.

For example:

Vishay - BZT03C200 PSPICE model copy-pasted into D1N4467 from the DIODE library.

[image]

[image]

Which gives me the desired result.

---

I've looked through all the gate drivers in the MFET_DRVR library, but there are no components that have the number of pins shown in the above datasheet, which is 9.

How can I go about using this model in PSPICE? I have looked into how to make custom components with specific numbers of pins/parameters/etc., but I was unsuccessful in making one work. Also, doing a google search has come up with a few forum posts, but many of them are amibiguous to me since I am unfamiliar in using Cadence.

Comment: Is one of the 9 pins the Silicon  Substrate?

Comment: The pins are: VDD, ENABLE, PD, IN-A, IN-B, OB, GND, VH, OA. It comes in a package with 16 pins, but the rest are NC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find documentation from another manufacturer that helped.

https://www.vishay.com/docs/63192/an841.pdf

http://www.vishay.com/docs/65038/an838.pdf

They were slightly dated, and there was still an issue after execution, with the simulation saying that one of the internal nodes 'X_U1' was undefined.

Then I found this post:
['Missing subcircuit' when creating a Pspice library part from the OPA188 Spice file provided by TI](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/148887/missing-subcircuit-when-creating-a-pspice-library-part-from-the-opa188-spice-f)

Which detailed how to remedy this problem, and everything worked perfectly!