# Nom.lib in OrCad

Tags: pspice, orcad

What is the nom.lib in orCad? Why do we need it when trying to simulate a circuit? When I was about to simulate, I saw a youtube video where the guy says that I need to go to 'configuration files' and add the nom.lib from Cadence's installation dir.

Comment: Your question is so vague, I'm afraid the only thing I can say is to ask the owner of the video. Otherwise a library holds subcircuits or models that are needed for that particular simulation.

Comment: Searching for this term in this SE have me [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/254133) and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/214825)